# Best practice to save data for anonymous users?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm building a web app and i'd like to allow anonymous users to use it and to save some data without signing up.

let's assume the user save a list of favorites image urls without singing up.

now i'm using this way: I save those favs in db and then i save the user's ip address
so every time the user go back he can see his past favs

of course this is a temp solution

what's the best way to associate that list to a specific user?
save it in a cookie?
some hybrid solution?

Comment: Give the user's browser a cookie with a unique value and use that value as a database key. The IP address is a terrible idea really because obviously they can move from Internet cafe to Internet cafe to their home to a hotel etc.

Comment: `what's the best way to associate that list to a specific user?` Make them not-anonymous. There is a reason why every site and its mother asks you to sign up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the "The Anonymous User Pattern": http://roshfu.com/2012/01/16/the-anonymous-user-pattern.html

Answer (score 2):

Do not use IP addresses; not only do they change frequently for home users, but there'll usually be a few (to hundreds) of people with the same IP.

Cookies could work, but they get sent on EVERY http request so you'll be slowing things down and wasting bandwidth (and probably hitting the cookie size limit quickly).

I suggest using JavaScript `localStorage`: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage